# Elementary computation of de Rham cohomology of punctured space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

Is there any elementary form of computing the de Rham cohomology groups of punctured space (without Mayer Vietoris or de Rham theorem)? I know how to do it for the punctured plane, using the form that is locally the differential of the angle in polar coordinates, but I can't figure it out for the punctured space.

Comment: Well, the analog of $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$ is $S^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$; so I'd be looking at $\sin \theta\,d \theta \wedge d \varphi$.